# How to compare elements in an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to find the "Valleys" and "Peaks" of numbers in an array. "Valleys" and "Peaks" pretty much mean that I need to compare each index with the two indexes around it. So if the middle index is larger than the indexes around it, its a "Peak", but if the index in the middle is smaller than the two indexes around it, its a "Valley". I have to do this for every number on every array line shown below:

```
    int[][] arrays = { 
        { 2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 9, 7, 8, },
        { 4, 4, 7, 4, 2, },
        { 2, 5, 3, 3, 7, 2, },
        { 1, 9, 3, 5, 2, 7, 3, 5, 1 },
        { 2, 8, 8, 7, 9, 9, 9, 3 },
        { 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, },
        { 1, 2, 5, 9, 10, },
    };
```

I tried to use if and else if but the smallest array goes to index 4 and if I try to use higher indexes the code will not run properly. Here is my attempt:

```
public class ValleyPeak {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arrays = { 
        { 2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 9, 7, 8, },
        { 4, 4, 7, 4, 2, },
        { 2, 5, 3, 3, 7, 2, },
        { 1, 9, 3, 5, 2, 7, 3, 5, 1 },
        { 2, 8, 8, 7, 9, 9, 9, 3 },
        { 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, },
        { 1, 2, 5, 9, 10, },
    };

  for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) 
     valley_peak(arrays[i]);

}

static void valley_peak(int[] a) {
    System.out.print("\narray: \n");
    //1
    if(a[0] > a[1]){
        System.out.println("[0] is a peak, ");
    }
    else if(a[0] < a[1]){
        System.out.println("[0] ia a valley, ");
    }
    //2
    if(a[1] > a[0] && a[1] > a[2]){
      System.out.println("[1] ia a peak, ");
    }
    else if(a[1] < a[0] && a[1] < a[2]){
        System.out.println("[1] ia a valley, ");
    }
    //3
    if(a[2] > a[1] && a[2] > a[3]){
      System.out.println("[2] ia a peak, ");
    }
    else if(a[2] < a[1] && a[2] < a[3]){
        System.out.println("[2] ia a valley, ");
    }
    //4
    if(a[3] > a[2] && a[3] > a[4]){
      System.out.println("[3] ia a peak, ");
    }
    else if(a[3] < a[2] && a[3] < a[4]){
        System.out.println("[3] ia a valley, ");
    }
    //4
    if(a[4] > a[3] && a[4] > a[5]){
      System.out.println("[4] ia a peak, ");
    }
    else if(a[4] < a[3] && a[4] < a[5]){
        System.out.println("[4] ia a valley, ");
    }
    //5
    if(a[5] > a[4] && a[5] > a[6]){
      System.out.println("[5] ia a peak, ");
    }
    else if(a[5] < a[4] && a[5] < a[6]){
        System.out.println("[5] ia a valley, ");
    }
    //6
    if(a[6] > a[5] && a[6] > a[7]){
      System.out.println("[6] ia a peak, ");
    }
    else if(a[6] < a[5] && a[6] < a[7]){
        System.out.println("[6] ia a valley, ");
    }
    //7
    if(a[7] > a[6] && a[7] > a[8]){
      System.out.println("[7] ia a peak, ");
    }
    else if(a[7] < a[6] && a[7] < a[8]){
        System.out.println("[7] ia a valley, ");
    }
    //8
    if(a[8] > a[7] && a[8] > a[9]){
      System.out.println("[8] ia a peak, ");
    }
    else if(a[8] < a[7] && a[8] < a[9]){
        System.out.println("[8] ia a valley, ");
    }
    //9
    if(a[9] > a[8] && a[9] > a[10]){
      System.out.println("[9] ia a peak, ");
    }
    else if(a[9] < a[8] && a[9] < a[10]){
        System.out.println("[9] ia a valley, ");
    }
  }
}
```

I am stuck on what I should do next? I am fairly new to arrays, watched some videos but still can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: You need to use a loop. You already have a loop in `main()`. Use another in your processor. You don't, for example, anywhere check if `a[10]` actually or if `a.length < 9`.

Answer (score 0):

So this program should solve the problem

```
public class Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arrays = {
                { 2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 9, 7, 8, },
                { 4, 4, 7, 4, 2, },
                { 2, 5, 3, 3, 7, 2, },
                { 1, 9, 3, 5, 2, 7, 3, 5, 1 },
                { 2, 8, 8, 7, 9, 9, 9, 3 },
                { 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, },
                { 1, 2, 5, 9, 10, },
        };

        for(int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
            int[] array = arrays[i];

            System.out.println("array: " + i);

            //Edge case first item of array
            if(array[0] > array[1]) {
                System.out.println("[0] is peak");
            }
            else if(array[0] < array[1]) {
                System.out.println("[0] is valley");
            }

            // loop for all items in the middle of the array
            for(int j = 1; j < array.length - 2; j++) {
                if(array[j-1] < array[j] && array[j+1] < array[j]) {
                    System.out.println("[" + j + "] is peak");
                }
                else if(array[j-1] > array[j] && array[j+1] > array[j]) {
                    System.out.println("[" + j + "] is valley");
                }
            }

            //Edge case last item of array
            int indexLastItem = array.length - 1;

            if(array[indexLastItem] > array[indexLastItem - 1]) {
                System.out.println("[" + indexLastItem + "] is peak");
            }
            else if(array[indexLastItem] < array[indexLastItem - 1]) {
                System.out.println("[" + indexLastItem + "] is valley");
            }


        }

    }

}
```

So you use 2 loops. The first for the array in the arrays, the second for the item in the array. You have to make a special condition for the first and last item in the array, because they don't have 2 neighbors. For the rest you just compare each item to the one before and after it.